# Updating treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza uma treeview conforme imagem e código abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FrontPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="IASD.ASCS.WebForm.register.group.Default" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/FrontPage.Master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link href="../../Content/template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-pt_BR.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function TreeNodeCheckChanged(event, control) {
        // Valid for IE and Firefox/Safari/Chrome.
        var obj = window.event ? window.event.srcElement : event.target;
        var source = window.event ? window.event.srcElement.id : event.target.id;
        source = source.replace(control.id + "t", control.id + "n");
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(source);
        if (checkbox != null && obj.tagName == "INPUT" && obj.type == "checkbox") {
            __doPostBack(checkbox.id, "");
        }
    }

    function validate() {
        //Campo Nome
        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtGroupName.ClientID%>").value.trim() == "") {
            alert("Informe o Nome");
            document.getElementById("<%=txtGroupName.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        } txtGroupName
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#form1").validationEngine();
    });

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="buttons">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnNew" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/New_4.png" OnClick="btnNew_Click" ToolTip="Novo Grupo" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/exclude_G.png" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" ToolTip="Excluir Grupo" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/save_all.ico" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ToolTip="Salvar Grupo" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" OnClientClick=" return validate()" />
</div>
<div class="esp_campo">
    <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabGroup" runat="server" TabIndex="0" Width="100%" CssClass="ajax__myTab" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Grupo" ID="tbgroups">
            <HeaderTemplate>Grupo</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text="Nome"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" CssClass="textbox_search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtGroupName" ErrorMessage="Preencha o campo 'Nome'!" ValidationGroup="vsGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrupoID" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="GridMain">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvGroup" Width="100%" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewUser" GridLines="None"
                        CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="gvGroup_RowDeleting"
                        OnRowUpdating="gvGroup_RowUpdating" ForeColor="#333333">

                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternativeUser" BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="GroupID" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="Name" />
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/edit_.png">
                                <FooterStyle Width="50px" />
                                <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/Grids_Deletes.png" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeaderGroup" BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPagerGroup" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowGroup" BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsGroup" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" ForeColor="Red" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Menus" ID="tbMenus">
            <HeaderTemplate>Menus Por Grupo</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="page_name">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTabName" runat="server" Text="Menus do Grupo"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="forms">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TreeView ID="treeMenu" runat="server" CssClass="AspNet-TreeView" ShowLines="True"
                                ShowCheckBoxes="All" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="treeMenu_TreeNodeCheckChanged" ShowExpandCollapse="True"
                                Enabled="true">
                                <RootNodeStyle CssClass="AspNet-TreeView-Root" />
                            </asp:TreeView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="treeMenu" EventName="TreeNodeCheckChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
    </cc1:TabContainer>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void gvGroup_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        IB.Group obj = IB.Group.GroupItem(int.Parse(gvGroup.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));

        hfGrupoID.Value = obj.GroupID.ToString();
        txtGroupName.Text = obj.Name.ToString();

        btnDelete.Visible = true;
        tbMenus.Enabled = true;

        TabGroup.ActiveTab = tbMenus;


        WebTreeView.ClearTreeView(treeMenu.Nodes);

        Business.MenuItem.MountGroupTreeView(treeMenu.Nodes, Master.listMenuGroup, null);
        treeMenu.Attributes.Add("onclick", "TreeNodeCheckChanged(event, this)");
        treeMenu.ExpandDepth = 0;

        Business.MenuItem.CheckTreeView(treeMenu.Nodes, Business.MenuItem.ListMenubyGroup(int.Parse(hfGrupoID.Value)));
//
    }
```

Ao clicar em um botão update deverá abrir a tela conforme a imagem acima para que seja configurado o tipo de acesso por grupo.

O problema que ocorre é que cada vez que é clicado no botão update é duplicado os menus por grupo.

Na imagem abaixo foi clicado três vezes no menu editar e foi triplicado as opções de menu por grupo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar? Não tenho certeza onde está o problema.

O método que limpa o treeview

```
public static void ClearTreeView(TreeNodeCollection NodeCollection)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in NodeCollection)
        {
            item.Checked = false;

            item.ImageUrl = "";

            if (item.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                ClearTreeView(item.ChildNodes);

        }
    }
```

O método que monta o treeview

```
 public static void MountGroupTreeView(WC.TreeNodeCollection cItens, List<MenuItem> listMenuGroup, int? ParentMenuItemID)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem ttItem in listMenuGroup.FindAll(p => p.ParentMenuItemID == ParentMenuItemID))
        {
            WC.TreeNode newItem = new WC.TreeNode(ttItem.NameMenuItem, ttItem.MenuItemID.ToString());
            newItem.SelectAction = WC.TreeNodeSelectAction.None;

            cItens.Add(newItem);

            if (listMenuGroup.FindAll(p => p.ParentMenuItemID == ttItem.ParentMenuItemID).Count > 0)
                MountGroupTreeView(newItem.ChildNodes, listMenuGroup, ttItem.MenuItemID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: tive que fazer um também que por sinal tinha varios nós, preferir usar um plugin Jquery. Você não acha melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta isso...

```
treeMenu.Nodes.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta pode ser algo vaga mas parece que o problema pode estar no facto de

```
WebTreeView.ClearTreeView(treeMenu.Nodes);
```

não limpar correctamente a TreeView. Dado que de seguida são adicionados novamentes os items à tree, isso explicaria o porque de os items serem duplicados cada vez que há uma actualização.

Comment: inclui esse método acima e aparentemete ele faz a limpeza corretamente.

Comment: Pelo que percebi o método ClearTreeView, apesar de limpr o estado do item, nunca apaga os items que estão na NodeCollection.
Chamar NodeCollection.Clear() deverá resolver o problema.